# Making $\sin(2k\pi x)$ an odd function about $x=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, even-and-odd-functions

I want to ask whether k should be even or odd   in order to make the function $$f(x)=\sin(2k\pi x)$$ to be an odd function about $x=\frac{1}{4}$.
I think that if it is an odd function, then, $$f(x+\frac{1}{4})=-f(x-\frac{1}{4})$$.
I sub it in; but it turns out I get to:
$$\sin(2k\pi x)\cos(\frac{1}{2}k\pi)x=0.$$
Then, I don’t know how to proceed.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x-\frac 1 4$. If $k$ is odd then $f(x)=\sin (2k\pi y+k\pi /2)=\sin (k\pi /2) \cos (2k\pi y)$. This is an even function of $y$. On the other hand if $k$ is even then  $f(x)=\sin(2k\pi y) \cos (k\pi /2)$ which is an odd function of $y$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One thing I don’t understand is if we set $y=x-\frac{1}{4}$. And the function is an odd function about y. This implies $f(-y)=-f(y)$; implying $f(\frac{1}{4}-x)=-f(x-\frac{1}{4})$ This doesn’t seem right for me. Since we want $f(\frac{1}{4}+x)=-f(\frac{1}{4}-x)$

Answer (score 1):

**$k$ should be even**

Because if $\sin(2\pi kx)$ is odd about $x=\frac{1}{4}$, then you're asking for what $k$ does $\sin\Big(2\pi k(\frac{1}{4})\Big)=0$

I.e;

$$\sin\Big(\frac{\pi k}{2}\Big)=0$$

This is because $\sin(\theta)$ is odd about $\theta$ only when $\sin(\theta)=0$. Therefore

$$\sin\Big(\frac{\pi k}{2}\Big)=0\implies\frac{\pi k}{2}=\pi n~~~~~\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\implies k=2n~~~~~\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

So $k$ can be any even integer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.